# How to insert C# CA screen/form in between wix screens/dialogs

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

My requirement is to insert C# CA form in between 2 Wix dialogs.

Details:

1. My first screen is wix dialog and on clicking Next button the Wix dialog should close and C# CA form should open.
2. When Next button is clicked in C# CA form, it should close and second Wix dialog should open.
3. When Back button is clicked in C# CA form, it should close and first Wix dialog should open.

How can I achieve in Wix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "C# CA form"?

Comment: CA is for 'custom action', as far as I can tell

Comment: Apart from the issues Van S raises, this is not even technically possible without a huge unclear amount of work. If you thought Windows Installer dialogs were just a bunch of .NET forms it might look straightforward, but they are not. You're asking how a Next button running off a Windows Installer dialog process can find and invoke a dialog from somewhere else, give it the correct focus and Z order, and then how your dialog can call the next Windows Installer dialog, give it focus, Z order etc. As Van S. says, just design your own WiX dialog for it or use a bootstrapper.

Comment: @PhilDW, Yes this seems to be not achievable. Seems Wix does not support this. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's not even WiX, it's the architecture of Windows Installer. You could do it with a WiX bootstrapper that replaces the MSI UI, but that requires you to supply most of the forms shown during the install. But the point is that you can insert your own C# forms into the sequence because if (for example) they are in a class library you can just call them from your bootstrapper. For example http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

Comment: @ PhillDW, when I was searching for Custom UI to replace progress dialog, I came to know about MsiSetExternalUI and MsiEmbeddedUI, is it possible to use them in MSI?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIU, you are going to create a custom action with the UI in it, and this goes against custom action design practices. You won't be able to have silent installations, for example. There's a list of CA best practices [here](http://www.msigeek.com/250/custom-actions-rules-and-best-practices).

It seems that adding a custom dialog to the installation UI chain is what you really need. There are several articles out there how to do it, for example, [this one](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html).

It might be the case that the UI experience you need is not reachable with the Windows Installer limited UI capabilities. In this case, you should either think of how to redesign it to leverage built-in options, or consider implementing a custom UI, which is far from trivial. Often, a [bootstrapper application](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/) can handle the complex UI part, and launch the pure MSI package installation.

Comment: Yes this seems to be not achievable. Seems Wix does not support this. Thanks for your reply.